# Image not load from network - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show images of movies with API in the flutter app, but when I want to show an image get the error of Handshake like this:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ============
The following HandshakeException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Connection terminated during handshake

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 

Image provider: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/xmbU4JTUm8rsdtn7Y3Fcm30GpeT.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/xmbU4JTUm8rsdtn7Y3Fcm30GpeT.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

The part of code and also I use one of the example links to share my problem:

```
 SizedBox(
           height: 200,
           width: 160,
           child: ClipRRect(
             child: Image.network(
               'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/xmbU4JTUm8rsdtn7Y3Fcm30GpeT.jpg',
               ),
             ),
           ),
```

And I have tried to get an image via Postman, the status code was 200 with the above link.

Comment: Is the console giving this on your emulator or also when you connect a real device to debug on? I tried your code, but everything works fine in my sample app.

Comment: Are you doing it on some browser? I mean, are you working on Flutter Web?

Comment: Yes, I'm running on emulator. Does image loaded in your sample app? - @Roderik

Comment: No, I'm working on Android studio emulator @BilalSaeed

Comment: Try 1. Flutter clean 2. Flutter pub get 3. Restart your IDE. 4. Ensure you have active internet connection. 5. Rebuild your project

Comment: Thanks, I did all of these but it doesn't work. @BilalSaeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about using a VPN which is not good. After changing the VPN app, the problem is solved.

**Update**:
Before I used qv2ray by using Shadowsocks of Surfshark, after changing the VPN [to Geph](https://geph.io/en/), images can be load from the network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).